# How do I use a "Class Module" or a "Module" in Visual Basic For Applications?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to create a collection in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) and can't figure out how to do this.  Can anyone either explain this to me or send me off to some links?

I've been working on this same "language issue" for several hours.  I've checked SO, google, MSDN, and F1 help to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you pls be more explicit about the collection you are looking to make - a collection of a number of the better class modules and collection links below.

*Class Modules*

1. Walkenbacks [colour button class module](http://www.j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip49.htm)
2. Pearson on [class modules](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Classes.aspx)
3. Peltier, [Chart event class module](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/chart-event-class-module-to-highlight-a-series/)

*Dictionaries v Collections*

1. Patrick Matthews [Using the Dictionary Class in VBA](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_3391.html)

Comment: #2 showed me the missing piece... every sample I've come across seems to have included parenthesis when adding() to the array.  Delete the parens, and all is well

Answer (score 3):

The basic approach is:

Declare a Collection object

```
Dim oCol As Collection
```

Create an instance of the object

```
Set oCol = New Collection
```

Add things to the collection

```
oCol.Add Item:=1, Key:="Item1IsANumber"
oCol.Add Item:="SomeString", Key:="Item2IsAString"
```

Refer to the items

```
z = oCol.Item(1)  ' z = 1
z = oCol.Item(2)  ' z = "SomeString"
z = oCol.Item("Item1IsANumber")  ' z = 1
z = oCol.Item("Item2IsAString")  ' z = "SomeString"
```

`CPearson.com` is a good reference for lots of things vba

Here's a [Link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm) to a collections page